# Scrolling NewsTicker is cutting off early

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a scrolling News Ticker in WPF that is used to convey alerts (their preference not mine).  The implementation works but I have found an issue which is more noticeable as the text gets longer.  The text scrolls and then abruptly stops and then restarts.

```
<Border Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0,3,0,3">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="Ticker"  Background="Transparent" >
                <StackPanel.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="NewsTicker">
                            <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <DoubleAnimation From="{Binding ElementName=Ticker, Path=ActualWidth}" To="{Binding ElementName=Ticker, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource NegConverter}}" Storyboard.TargetName="translate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0:0:35" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="WrapPanel.MouseEnter">
                        <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="NewsTicker" />
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="WrapPanel.MouseLeave">
                        <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="NewsTicker" />
                    </EventTrigger>
                </StackPanelPanel.Triggers>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NewsTicker, IsAsync=True}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
                    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="translate" />
                    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanelPanel>
        </Border>
```

I would like the text to scroll from the Right to the Left until it scrolls off the screen and then come back in once again from the Right in an endless loop.

I tried a couple of different methods from SO, including animating Margins with Thickness animation and as well as an example using a canvas, but neither of them actually worked at all.

Any advice?

Comment: Create a UserControl and handle the animation in code.  At least you'd have all the control you need over it.  I could see a very simple version (probably flickery :/) that simply removes characters from the front of the message and appends new ones to the back...  But then, I'm lazy.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you try stripping your Margin/Padding=0 properties and throw a tiny delay on your `BeginTime` for your DoubleAnimation like maybe BeginTime="0:0:.5", I dont have a wpf proj up to test on, but if that doesnt have a positive effect I think I'll make something later, I've done this before but its been awhile.

Comment: Would it be possible to also give your NegativeConverter? Might help with building it and working out what the problem is - does it just make convert +x to -x I assume?

Comment: @David yea it literally just returns the negative of what's passed in.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the key to it not jumping is binding to the right things - we want to bind the `To` field to the `ActualWidth` of the TextBlock, not the `ActualWidth` of the `StackPanel` (which is smaller)

So we can change the DoubleAnimation to:

```
<DoubleAnimation From="{Binding ElementName=Ticker, Path=ActualWidth}" To="{Binding ElementName=TickerTextBlock, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource NegConverter}}" Storyboard.TargetName="translate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0:0:4" />
```

And add a `x:Name="TickerTextBlock"` to the `TextBlock` containing the Text.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work straight off (and instead it uses the initial value of 0 from the binding pre text loading for the animation! :|). Animations are often very fickle like this - I believe it has something to do with only being created and run **once**, and so the value of the binding is only used when the animation is first run. (but I may be mis-understanding)

Certainly one solution which worked on my copy of your code is to ensure that the text loads first, (ie we place the `TextBlock` *above* the animation in the XAML, and change the binding so that it is not async.)

If you wish to keep the async, then I believe we'd need to restart the double animation when the text changes. I would look into this further, but it's really late and I'm going to head to bed (sorry!)

Comment: I tried this and it feels right.  However for some reason when the beginning of the text reaches the left of the screen it starts over instead of continuing to scroll out.  I even changed NegConverter to double the value before returning the negative but it had no effect.  Changing the To binding back to Ticker causes it to continue scrolling as desired, but with a side effect I also don't understand.  The end of the text is immediately followed by the beginning of the text and after 6 words it all resets again.  I did drop duration and added SpeedRatio=".03"

Comment: Indeed, it's due to the Animation loading with the wrong binding initially. If you put a debug point in the NegConverter, you can see that the correct value is put into the binding (but only after the erroneous value, 0 is put in), so we need some way of updating the animation and changing its 'To' field as it runs. I haven't had a chance to look into how that might be done though unfortunately!